# how to slice string if numbers starts in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, react-native

I have strings like these

```
total sales 234 rs
total cost 651 rs
```

and I want to get only

end result should look like this

```
total sales
total cost
```

how can i get that please help thanks

Comment: Do you only want to extract the total number of sales and cost from string?

Comment: I only want names

Comment: What the end result should look like?

Comment: please check updated ans

Comment: `'total sales 234 rs'.split(/\s*\d/)[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always want to cut it off just before the first number, you could find the index of the first number:

```
const index = 'total sales 234 rs'.search(/\d/);
```

And then just get the substring:

```
substring(0, index - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let str = 'total sales 234 rs';
let result = str.split(' ').slice(0,2).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string can contain more than two main words
For eg `Total goods cost 200 rs`

then use the below function

```
function reducer(str) { // where str is the initial string
 const modifiedStr = str.split(' ').reduce((acc, substr) => {
  if(!parseInt(substr, 10) && substr !== 'rs') acc+=substr+' ';
  return acc;
 }, "");
 return modifiedStr.slice(0,modifiedStr.length - 2);
}
```